# Getting weird errors from refactoring react native styles

Tags: react-native

I'm getting a weird error that doesn't make any sense simply from copying and pasting styles from inline to the StyleSheet.create method to clean things up. It says that "bottomBorderStyle" is not a valid style property. It worked when it was inline so this makes no sense. The error even persists if I use the inline styling but also keep the StyleSheet, and then if I delete the StyleSheet, the error goes away.

I've tried everything I can think of to make sure I didn't do anything stupid with the syntax as I am very new to react native, and I just can't think of a way that this error makes sense. Of course I can just leave the inline style that works but I really want to learn why this happening and what I might be doing wrong. There is a bit of code left out between the points I show below. I can post the rest if it's relevant.
Update: the error also goes away if I remove the 'Bottom' part from the border attributes..

```
render() {
     return(
           <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{
                                     backgroundColor: 'white',
                                     borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                     borderBottomStyle: 'dashed',
                                     borderBottomRadius: 10,
                                     width: '90%',
                                     alignItems: 'center',
                                     flexDirection: 'row',
                                     justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                                 }}>
               </View>
        );
    }
}
//Error goes away if I delete from here down
const styles = StyleSheet.create( {
    FlexContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomStyle: 'dashed',
        borderBottomRadius: 10,
        width: '90%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The code looks absolutely fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use styling as follows

```
<View style={styles.FlexContainer}></View>
```

Comment: I think the OP is saying he has done that and the error shows. Even if he isn't using the styles, the error shows if the property is within the object